# Unable to display webcam stream in react

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, reactjs, numpy, video-streaming

Im trying to display my webcam stream but it shows only [blank section](https://ibb.co/r501ywJ).

My environment is ubuntu 18-06, python-3.6.
Heres what Ive tried (I suspect the issue could be due to src line (but I stil dont know).

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const VideoFeed = () => {
    const VideoFeedSection = styled.section`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 40px 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 45vw;
        h2 {
            margin-top : 0;
            font-size: 45px;
            line-height: 1;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #013087;
            text-align: center;
        }
`
    return (
            <VideoFeedSection className='some-space'>
                <h2>Video Feed - classroom 1</h2>
                <iframe allowFullScreen
                        title = 'camera feed'

            // !!! TO CHANGE !!!
                        src="//:0"
                        frameBorder="0"
                        width="100%"
                        height="576" />
            </VideoFeedSection>
    );
};

export default VideoFeed;
```

Heres the error from chrome console

```
Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `webkitallowfullscreen`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: webkitallowfullscreen="true" or webkitallowfullscreen={value.toString()}.
    in iframe (at VideoFeed.jsx:24)
    in section (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.section)
    in styled.section (at VideoFeed.jsx:22)
    in VideoFeed (at App.js:31)
    in main (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by [styled.main)]
    in styled.main (at App.js:30)
    in App (at src/index.js:7) index.js:1375
```

Video stream source is simply coming from webcam

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this .

```
<iframe allowFullScreen="true"
    title='camera feed'

    // !!! TO CHANGE !!!
    src="//:0"
    frameBorder="0"
    width="100%"
    height="576" />
```

or you can do like this

```
<iframe src="your_page_url"
    allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
    mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen"
    msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen"
    oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen"
    webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" />
```

you can use src file in videoCapture argument like below .

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
```

Comment: Added video source stream (which is my webcam basically), but dont know what value shall I put in "src" section of the code so as to connect to webcam source

Comment: it didnt work. cap = cv2.VideoCapture(src), here src has to be 0 for the webcam to work. But how do I communicate this stream to the VideoFeedSection

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you are seeing in the console is because allowFullScreen doesn't support boolean as a value.

You can solve that warning by adding settings `"true"` as the the value.

```
    <iframe 
      allowFullScreen="true"
      webkitallowfullscreen="true"
      mozallowfullscreen="true"
```

See: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7848#issuecomment-334594775

However, that is not the reason why you are seeing a blank screen. What is the source that are you loading in the iframe?

Comment: Thanks christian. I also think video source is not getting detected and that where I need help. Ive added the video source section (webcam is being displayed) and I want that webcam stream to be displayed.